# yocto recipe how to install file to rootfs

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe, yocto-wic

sorry I am a little new to syntax of yocto, this is how I have modified my recipe:

```
LICENSE  = "LGPLv2.1"
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SRC_URI = "file://myscript.sh"
FILES_${PN} += "${sysconfdir}/init.d/myscript.sh"

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/myscript.sh ${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d/
}
```

The recipe is added to the build, because if I remove the LICENSE line the yocto image will not be baked.
The folder where the recipe is kept is named "customssh", inside this folder I have the recipe named customssh_0.1.bb and a subfolder named "files" where the myscript.sh is kept.
After I have baked the image, I run this command to see if the myscript.sh has been placed in the rootfs:
find . -name 'myscript*'
which will return where the file is held:

```
./meta-swi/common/recipes-core/customssh/files/myscript.sh
```

In the recipe, is this line correct?

```
install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/myscript.sh ${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d/
```

Comment: are you sure your package is being installed?

Comment: Hi, try removing the last `myscript.sh` after the `init.d` path, just use only: `${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d`

Answer (score 1):

If this is the root recipe and not a `bbappend` one use `do_install` instead of `do_install_append`

Make sure that `${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d` is created before copying to it

```
do_install(){
   install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d
   install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/myscript.sh ${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d/
}
```

Now, make sure to specify the file you installed so that the `do_package` will not fail

```
FILES_${PN} += "${sysconfdir}/init.d/myscript.sh"
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, I have modified my question accordingly, sorry but I am a little new to yocto syntax....